# Clearing backgroundimage of panel

Tags: c#, windows, forms, panel

Using c# windows forms.

I'm using the backgroundImage of a panel to draw. I want to remove all drawings from the panel.

How can I simply do this?

Comment: Have you already tried it to see with your own eyes if it is?

Comment: Well, is it? Why don't you try it before posting a question?

Comment: Are you modifying the actual Image being displayed in the backround?...or are you using the Paint() event?  Give us some details...

Answer (score 3):

If you set a BackgroudImage, then use

```
this.myPanel.BackgroundImage = null;
```

to remove it...

Answer (score 3):

You can not use panel.backgroundImage.Dispose because there is not Dispose method of a Control.BackgroundImage property. You can use

```
panel.BackgroundImage = null;
```

to remove all the contents of a panel.

Make it clear that, The Dispose method is available only for controls, leaves the control in an unusable state. After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the control so the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the control was occupying.

Answer (score 1):

these both codes works fine.

```
this.myPanel.BackgroundImage = null;
```

or

```
this.myPanel.BackgroundImage = base.BackgroundImage;
```